# why is form_ tag code is not working in ruby mine 5.4.3.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I am building an ROR application in ruby mine .But the following doesn't seems to run `

```
<%= form_tag upload_index_path({:action => 'uploadFile'},
                               :multipart => true) do  %>
<p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
  <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>`

This code is in my view file. I am trying to build a site where i can upload files. Everything appears good but when i click the upload button the file doesn't get uploaded only the url changes. Why is that??
```

**This is my controller code**

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html.erb'
  end
  def uploadFile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

**This is my model code**

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

I have not been able to find solution. I have been trying for a week.

Comment: how r u saving file in application? It is better to use gem paperclip  .

Answer (score 0):

In your form_tag declaration, remove the multipart from the path options as follows:

```
<%= form_tag upload_index_path({:action => 'uploadFile'}) , :multipart => true do  %>                    
    <p>
        <label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
        <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>
    </p>

    <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>

<% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Can you post any output that rails server displays when it breaks.